# Different types of DDoS attacks

Tags: attacks, ddos

What is behavior of UDP flood, TCP SYN flood, Ping of Death and Smurf attack?

Comment: I think your solution is [there](http://bfy.tw/df5)

Comment: There is a lot of data available on this. Have you done research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do DoS/DDoS work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-do-dos-ddos-work)

Answer (score 1):

Ping of Death, Teardrop etc. were local attacks for broken TCP/IP stack implementations and caused affected systems to crash (mostly in late 90-ties).

Smurf in an example of distributed (DDoS) attack, which uses ICMP Echo Request with spoofed address to cause victim systems to be flooded by ICMP Echo Reply packets.

TCP SYN flood is an attack to overflow victim's TCP connection queue, so it won't be able to handle new incoming connections.

UDP flood is just sending multiple UDP packets to fill victim's bandwitdh.