# How can i reject connection from LAN and WAN to some ports?

Tags: ports, iptables

Scanning with `nmap`, I discovered that there are 3 open ports on my server. I want to deny any access to these ports from any machine, regardless of whether it is on the same LAN or via WAN. How do I write an `iptables` rule for this?

Comment: What type of server is it? More details required about the operating system of the host with the open ports and any networking devices you have otherwise you will end up with a pretty generic answer :)

Comment: I think it doesnt matter what type and what os is it! I just want generic answer :)

Comment: Well if its `iptables`, then Linux / IPtables, no?

Comment: @sophist it matters a lot what type of system it is because the answer will vary greatly between Windows, Linux, BSD, etc.

Comment: yes it's linux.. How to restrict connexion to those ports via lan and wan ? (i don't want any other machine except mine have access to those ports) Do u have an idea ? :)

Comment: You should indeed block them using iptables if other hosts should not have access - but you also need to work out why they are open in the first place and either remove redundant servers (i.e. daemons) or configure them so they don't listen on interfaces they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to block all open ports on a specific interface? If so, you can use the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -i <interfaceName> -j DROP
```

for example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

where eth0 is usually for LAN interface

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
```

usually for WAN

Comment: How can i know the interface name (lan and wan) ?

Comment: use the `ifconfig -a`. The last line for the interface description will contain `Base address:0xe800` where 0xe800 stands for LAN interface and `0x2000` for WAN. There is a file on linux system which explains all these, I don't really remember where exactly it is situated on the system. Usually by default eth0 is for LAN and eth1 i for WAN. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deny access to all the machines ("any machine from LAN and WAN") it is better to either stop those services or bind them to the localhost. This way there will be no chance of messing up iptable rules.

Still, you can use IPTABLES to block access to specific ports as well.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <port of the service you want to block> -j DROP
```

Repeat the above rule for all the ports you want to block access to.

Answer (score 1):

To close an individual port, you can do the following.

```
iptables -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Adjust `tcp` to be `udp` if that's the case, change `80` to the appropriate port. That will reject anything that didn't come from the local loopback interface.

See also [Reject IP packets with an ICMP error, or just drop them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3290/836)

Note that this solves the individual problem, but in a general sense you should explicitly allow which ports you wish to have open and then [deny the rest](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31932/836). Particularly since you probably still want to access these ports from your the local machine, that adds a lot more convenience in rule writing as well.

Comment: there are web services opening those ports..I think that this rule "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT" will deny any input, isn't it ?

Comment: @sophist Can you rewrite that? I can't understand what you tried to say.

Comment: In fact there are 3 web services installed in my machine (= 3 open ports).. I have to deny any other machine connecting with the same lan and wan from using those ports.. 

Is the rule u mentionned realize that ?

Comment: No, it does not. You'll need to set a rule for each port.